# Exporting extern templates from shared object

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, extern

Given the following example, with GCC under GNU/Linux :

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(export_templates CXX)
include(GenerateExportHeader)

set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET hidden)

add_library(mylib SHARED header.hpp mylib.cpp)
generate_export_header(mylib)

add_executable(myexe header.hpp main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(myexe mylib)
```

header.hpp:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
template<typename T>
struct foo
{
    std::size_t bar() {
        std::vector<T> t;
        t.resize(10);
        return t.size();
    }
};

extern template struct foo<int>;
```

mylib.cpp:

```
#include "header.hpp"

#include <mylib_export.h>
template struct MYLIB_EXPORT foo<int>;
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "header.hpp"

int main()
{
    foo<int> f;
    return f.bar();
}
```

I get the following linker error:

```
[ 75%] Linking CXX executable myexe
CMakeFiles/myexe.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
main.cpp:(.text+0x1f): undefined reference to `foo<int>::bar()'
```

What can I do to get this to link, with the following requirements:

- Should work on linux (.so), macOS (.dylib), windows (.dll)
- With latest gcc, msvc, and clang.
- Without adding `MYLIB_EXPORT` to the definition of `struct foo` (since in the real case, `struct foo` is not under my control).

Comment: What code is in mylib_export.h? I've never tried this, but as for me you declare specialization of foo<int>, but never define it, so it has nothing to do with dynamic linking, even static should not work.

Comment: the code generated by CMake's generate_export_header... stuff like `#define MYLIB_EXPORT __attribute__ ((dllexport))` with GCC / Clang and `#define MYLIB_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)` on MSVC. Static linking works fine actually, and it is not specialization, but explicit instantiation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/class_template#Explicit_instantiation

Comment: Doesm't CMAKE_CXX_VISIBILITY_PRESET hidden makes symbols hidden by default and MYLIB_EXPORT make it visible again? Now I see your problem